# Making a psd file ready for sign printers needing an ai file, needs to be very clear to blow up

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I made a business card for a family friend on Photoshop,  went all gold,  they got their business cards printed but now they want a sign made with the logo I made for them.  So it needs to be blown up to a large scale but they can't use the psd file I made because it comes out too blurry.  The printer can only us ai files.  I opened the psd file in illustrator then saved it as a eps as requested by the printer,  but when he opened it and zoomed in it was still blurt.  How can I make this work?

Comment: You must **recreate** the artwork in Illustrator as vector shapes. You *can not* use any part of the Photoshop **raster** image. [See here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/if-i-import-a-psd-file-with-one-layer-into-ai-and-then-save-as-ai-file-is-thi), [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop), and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97003/can-i-convert-a-psd-or-jpeg-file-to-ai-file) It is generally a poor idea to ever create a "logo" with Photoshop.

Comment: Scott's comment is correct but I just wanted to add that a commercial printer can print a PSD file, it's just that your graphic was designed smaller than you intended to print so enlarging the graphic which will pixelate it.

Comment: @AndrewH *signage* is often different and can really make vector mandatory at times. It does depend upon the sign though.

Comment: As @Scott says, some sign places cut vinyl and want sheer vectors: `.eps`, `.ai`, `.dxf`, `.dwg`, some even take `.svg` - so it depends upon the printer’s pipeline and production technology what they need - but clearly a pixel-painted business card design element will need to be redrawn as vector art prior to any use such as larger-scale signage or vinyl cutting - if they can print from raster files, designing in vector and then exporting to the size needed is the best practice anyway, and allows easy vector export as well as vari-sized raster exports.

Comment: "I made a business card for a family friend on Photoshop, went all gold"

Except that it didn't. Please, do not "Design" in PhotoIShouldNotUseItForEverythingShop.

Answer (score 1):

As @Scott says, some sign places cut vinyl and want sheer vectors: `.eps`, `.ai`, `.dxf`, `.dwg`, some even take `.svg` - so it depends upon your specific printer’s pipeline and production technology what file format and graphic methods they need.

Clearly a small-format pixel-painted business card design element *will **need** to be **redrawn** as **vector art*** prior to any use such as larger-scale signage or vinyl cutting; even if they *can* print from raster files, *designing in **vector*** and then *exporting* to a raster file in the size needed is the best practice anyway, and allows easy vector export as well as vari-sized raster exports.

*You need to redraw **as vector art** from the get-go.*

Hope this helps.